# When is the construction “si + imparfait” used?

Tags: sens, conjonctions, imparfait, conditions

When do we use this formula: *si + imparfait* ?

What are the applications of it ?

> **Si** on **sortait** ensemble ce soir ?

What's about the question form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je vois deux utilisations au « si + imparfait »:

- Pour exprimer un souhait ou un regret, proposer une idée:

  > Si on sortait ensemble ce soir ?
  >   *What about going out together tonight?*
  >   *What if we went out together tonight?*
  >
  > Si seulement j'avais écouté ma mère !
  >   *If only I had listen to my mom!*

  Dans ce cas, le *if* n'est pas tout le temps utilisé pour la traduction anglaise.
- Pour exprimer une condition:

  > Si je pouvais, je viendrais t'aider à finir tes devoirs.
  >   *If I could, I would help you finish your homework.*

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce cas l'emploi de **si** + **imparfait**  dans une phrase se terminant par un point d'interrogation indique une suggestion/une propostion.

---

This sentence :
si + imparfait + question mark at the end of the sentence
 implies a suggestion or a propostion.

It is the equivalent of :
*What about (how about) going out tonight?*